# How to find an accuracy of a classifier

Tags: matlab, knn

I am using the KNN classifier and I found the knnclassify does the classification for me in MATLAB.

code:

```
Class = knnclassify(TestVec,TrainVec, TrainLabel);
```

The problem I face now, knnclassify just classifies the points and gives them a value but I would like to find the accuracy of this classification.

I tried something like this:

```
Class = knnclassify(TestVec,TrainVec, TrainLabel);
cp = classperf(TestLabel,Class);
cp.CorrectRate
```

It is giving me this error:

```
??? Error using ==> classperf at 149
When the class labels of the CP object are numeric, the output
of the classifier must be all non-negative integers or NaN's.

Error in ==> KNN at 3
cp = classperf(TestLabel,Class);
```

Is there a better method to find the accuracy of a classifier or what corrections should I do to improve my code above?

Comment: Well, what does the vector `Class` look like? Is it a vector of non-negative integers of NaNs?

Comment: class is a 117 x1 matrix.. the values are either 1 or -1... 1 for postive and -1 for negative

Comment: can you try setting the `-1` entries to `0` and see if that has any effect?

Comment: you mean changing my trainlabel and testlabel values to 0 or 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the values of the labels should be 0 or 1.

the code to type :

```
cp = classperf(TrainLabel);   
Class = knnclassify(TestVec,TrainVec, TrainLabel);
cp = classperf(TestLabel,Class);
cp.CorrectRate
```

Answer (score 0):

```
maybe, you can use this code to understand...

sample = [2 12   ;47 18 ;46.7 12]
training=[46.7 12;45 11 ;46.7 13]
group = [1;2;1]
class = knnclassify(sample, training, group)


cp = classperf(class,group);%to compare 2 matrix, which is have the same row n column
cp.CorrectRate*100
```